# Google Apps Script opening a document by name?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a program where if a document doesn't exist yet, create it, but if it does, edit it.
I tried to do it like this:

```
    if(check == false){
    var doc = DocumentApp.create('Announcements for '+ data[0][2]);
  }
  

    else{
        var doc = DocumentApp.openById('Announcements for '+ data[0][2]);
      }
```

Here, 'check' is true when the file exists, and false if it doesn't.
I'm assuming that the problem is that I'm using 'openById' incorrectly.
What is the document id, and how can my code know what it is?
Thanks in advance!

(First-time user here, sorry for any formatting errors)

edit: I'll be making multiple docs, and all I know about the doc I need to open is its name

Comment: Your [mcve] is incomplete making it difficult for us to determine the issue with your code.  Please provide and complete example of the code include function declaration.  How do we know that your description about undefined variable check are correct perhaps that's the issue.  Please provide something more complete and reproducible for us and perhaps we can help.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter of `openById()` is the file id of the document you are trying to access. File id is the value between the "/d/" and the "/edit" of your Google Document URL.

**Example**: `https://docs.google.com/document/d/12345/edit` where 12345 is the id.

**DocumentApp** does not have method for opening documents using file name. The only available methods are `openById()` and `openByUrl()`.

An alternative is to use **DriveApp** to get the **name**, **id**, and **mimetype** of the files inside your Drive or Drive folder.

### Example:

*The code below will open a document if it matches the fileName 'Announcement 1' :*

**Code:**

```
function openByName() {
  //open specific folder and get the files
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('insert folder id here').getFiles();
  var fileName = 'Announcement 1';
  //The code below will search for Announcement 1 file and open it if found.
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileType = file.getMimeType();
    //Check if the filename matches 'Announcement 1' and the file type should be google-apps.document
    if(file.getName() == fileName && fileType == 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'){
      //Open document
      DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
    }
  }
}
```

**Test Folder:**
[image]

### References:

- [Class DocumentApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app)
- [Class DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)